# Nested serializers saving

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a nested serializer to be able to save from parent POST the childs as well. I have the following model:

```
class Parent:
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Child:
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'Parent', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='child_list')
```

And following serializer:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    child_list = ChildSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'child_list')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        rules_data = validated_data.pop('child_list')
        parent = Parent.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for rule_data in rules_data:
            Child.create(**rule_data)

        return parent
```

But when i am posting i get error

```
KeyError at /parent/
'child_list'
```

Do i miss something ?

Comment: What was the POST data?

Answer (score 2):

Read only on child list should be false

```
child_list = ChildSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
```